# Problem with reference variable as function parameter in c++

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I have declared a class as :

```
    class Actuator
    {
    
    public :
        enum class Action
        {
                /*my enum member*/
        };
        
    private:
       /* my data member*/

    public :
        Actuator(uint8_t number);
        Actuator(uint8_t number, String& relay_config_string, String& led_config_string);
        Actuator(uint8_t number, const char* relay_config_string, const char* led_config_string);

        void set_relay_config (String& relay_config_string);
        void set_relay_config (const char* relay_config_string);
        String get_relay_config (void);
        
        void set_led_config (String& led_config_string);
        void set_led_config (const char* led_config_sring);
        String get_led_config (void);
        
        void set_state (bool state, bool change_flag = true);
        void set_state (String& state, bool change_flag = true);
        void toggle (bool change_flag = true);
        String get_state (void);

        
    };
```

and defined it on Actuator.cpp file.

In main.cpp file i wrote :

```
int main ()
{
Actuator ac;

ac.set_state(app_cmd.get_command_parameter().substring(2), false);
ac.set_relay_config(app_cmd.get_command_parameter().substring(2));
return 0;
}
```

The (ac.set_state(app_cmd.get_command_parameter().substring(2), false);) is ok but in (ac.set_relay_config(app_cmd.get_command_parameter().substring(2));) line i have following error :

> no instance of overloaded function
> "my_program::Actuator::set_relay_config" matches the argument list --
> argument types are: (String) -- object type is:
> my_program::ActuatorC/C++(304)

Edit : When i change `void set_relay_config (String& relay_config_string);` to `void set_relay_config (String relay_config_string);` (i.e remove &) it will be solved.

Comment: Either remove `&` from `String&` in the function declaration/definition, or put the substring in a variable and pass that. Your choice depends on what `set_relay_config` is supposed to do with the string.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ok, but what is ok with "ac.set_state(app_cmd.get_command_parameter().substring(2), false);" ? Those have same deceleration and passed same argument to them

Comment: You can't take lvalue reference of temporary as temporary is not lvalue. Perhaps your String class has operator bool() so first overload of set_state is used.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Yes when i navigate to deceleration of set_state (with ctrl+left click)  i see that  first overload of set_state is used. What do you mean about "String class has operator bool()" ?

Comment: I just guessed since otherwise how can String argument match with bool parameter?

Comment: @ÖöTiib There is an overloaded maethod taking String&, see void set_state (String& state, bool change_flag = true); The problem is with the reference and pr-value. See my answer below.

Comment: @Greg there indeed is but called is set_state (bool state, bool change_flag = true) as OP confirmed 2 comments above. Your answer does not answer to question yet.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Yes, but OP checked this with navigating via ctrl+click, not by debugging. His original problem was with "no instance of overloaded function" error.

Comment: @Greg if you carefully read the question then that wasn't issue with set_state.

Comment: @ÖöTiib You are right, sorry I read that too quickly. However, I still think the problem is that OP is trying to pass an r-value as reference. He should either add const or pass by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here:

```
ac.set_state(app_cmd.get_command_parameter().substring(2), false);
ac.set_relay_config(app_cmd.get_command_parameter().substring(2));
```

is you are passing a pr-value of the String type returned by `substring()` method, see:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

R-value cannot be modified, so it cannot be passed to a function by reference.

To solve this problem you either need to:

- pass it as const reference - const String&:

  `void set_state (const String& state, bool change_flag = true);`

  `void set_relay_config (const String& relay_config_string);`
- pass it as value type - String:

  `void set_state (String state, bool change_flag = true);`

  `void set_relay_config (String relay_config_string);`

Comment: 1.You mean function's return variable is a r-value? 2.pr-value differ from r-value?

Comment: 1. Yes, substring() returns a temporary value that cannot be passed as a reference.
Please see the link I attached. 2. prvalue is a subclass of rvalue.